# Python chat client: the server receives commands along with previously sent messages

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, client-server, chat

I'm currently working on a project for a class. It consists in code a simple chat client (protocol given by the teacher) to do (at first) some simple tasks.

My problem is that after I send a mensage on the globlal channel or in other channel that doesn't require the use of a command, and try to send any command, the server replies with an error, saying something like: "msgbeforemsgbeforeCOMMAND" is not a valid command. I just cannot figure it out why this is happening...

(*another thing, note that my dictionary is not printing the right why, I dont know why to*)

ex: 
[chat running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9DRH.png)

```
import socket, select, string, sys
import threading
import time

def prompt():
    sys.stdout.write('<You>: ')
    sys.stdout.flush()

tLock = threading.Lock()
shutdown = False

def receber(sock):
    while not shutdown:
        try:
            tLock.acquire()
            while True:
                data = sock.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    print ('Disconnected from server\n')
                    sys.exit()
                else:
                    print ('<server>: %s' % (data.decode()))
                    sys.stdout.write(data)
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            tLock.release()


#Main Function
if __name__ == "__main__":

    host = 'mini.alunos.di.uevora.pt'
    port = 143

    #IP do servidor
    try:
        busca_ip = socket.gethostbyname( host )
        print ('Chat server IP: %s Port: %d \nNow connecting...\n' %(busca_ip, port))

    except socket.gaierror:
        #Não conseguiu o IP do servidor
        print ('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting.')
        sys.exit()

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(3)

    # connectar ao host
    try :
        s.connect((busca_ip, port))
        s.setblocking(0)
    except :
        print ('Unable to connect to the server.')
        sys.exit()

    print ('Connected to chat server. You may start chatting\n')

    COM_ARG = {'_Comando_': '_Argumentos_',
               'NICK': '<nickname> [\<password>]',
               'MSG': '<recipient> \<message>',
               'ENTER': '<room>',
               'LEAVE': '<room> [\<message>]',
               'RLIST':'',
               'ULIST':''}

    for chave, valor, in COM_ARG.items():
        print (("%s %s") % (chave,valor))

    print ('\n')

    comandos = COM_ARG.keys()


    #criar thread para o socket
    t = threading.Thread(target = receber, args=(s,))
    t.start()

    while True:

        msg = input('<You>: ')
        msg = msg.strip()
        msg12 = msg.upper()
        msg12 = msg12.split()
        try:
            if msg12[0] in comandos:
                msg = msg + '\n'
        except:
            pass
        s.send(msg.encode())
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

btw, `sys.stdout.write(data)` is doing something there?

Hope you could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

> (another thing, note that my dictionary is not printing the right why, I dont know why to)

Dictionary doesn't respect order.

> My problem is that after I send a mensage on the globlal channel or in other channel that doesn't require the use of a command, and try to send any command, the server replies with an error, saying something like: "msgbeforemsgbeforeCOMMAND" is not a valid command. I just cannot figure it out why this is happening...

It's not just a problem with the code, the server recives the msgs, and keeps them until a '\n' appears, just then interprets the command. It's a "problem" with the protocol, but the code must be changed.

> btw, sys.stdout.write(data) is doing something there?

Supposedly does the samething that `print (data.decode())` does, but doesn't work in my case. I'm not sure.